# Emirates ID90 multi-segment booking rules (standby / subload / staff tickets)

Tags: emirates, standby

Does anybody know exactly what rules apply to booking these tickets?
You can book up to 6 segments and if there is something the system doesn't like you usually get the message "two departures from/to same country are not permitted".

But examples show this is clearly not correct, or maybe incomplete/inaccurate.

Even a simple return flight from London to Sydney for example involves two departures from Dubai, but this obviously is allowed.

Then I tried e.g.

```
FRA-DXB
DXB-SYD
SYD-CHC
MEL-SIN
SIN-DXB
DXB-FRA
```

but that is not allowed.

It looks like the exact rules are more complicated, maybe involving backtracking or equivalence within a zone like Asia-Pacific or something, but I find no documentation on this. Maybe there are some experts out there who know more?

Many thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 2):

Your itinerary is technically allowed and could be booked as an open jaw with stopovers. For example I have booked successfully BOS->DXB->BKK->SYD->CHC, AKL->DPS->(DXB)->BOS

However, it took an awful amount of tries to actually get this to price out properly and at an acceptable price. The whole thing seems very fragile (for reasons I don't fully understand).

1. You have to make sure that the class of service you are looking for is available on EACH leg of the flight. A single downgrade will blow this up.
2. Make sure all segments are on Emirates metal. Do NOT choose a code share.
3. I'm not sure you can do 2 stopovers in DBX. We did one stopover and one layover (Which is the DXB in parenthesis) So we entered this as BOS->DXB->BKK->SYD->CHC, AKL->DPS->BOS and Emirates inserted the DXB layover between Bali and Boston automatically

I suggest removing one of the DXB's as an explicit stop and see what happens.

FWIW: we managed to get this to price out as First Saver fare and we got an awesome deal and an awesome experience: Good Luck !

**UPDATE**: I was able to price your itinerary  in First Class in April 2024 for 12000 Euro without the second stopover in Dubai.

Comment: Thanks that is very useful info. All I am doing is economy so that is not an issue.
But it seems like the booking system for standby is a little different - I can only enter max. 6 segments. Not sure about open jaw though must try that. Also Emirates no longer fly BKK-SYD afaik, but most interesting to see others have also pondered this, thanks!